# How to apply max word count validation on text-angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, textangular

The below code is for character validation. Now I want same type of validation for maximum word.

```
<text-angular ta-toolbar="[['undo','redo'], ['bold','italics','underline'], ['justifyLeft','justifyCenter','justifyRight','justifyFull'], ['wordcount']]" ng-model="description" name = "desc" ta-max-text="20" ></text-angular><br />

<span ng-show="form.desc.$error.taMaxText">Input is too long!</span>
```

In other words I want an alternative of "ta-max-text" for max words. Any inbuilt or custom validator for same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've done with "taMaxText", you must build your own directive or just use [one someone already made](https://gist.github.com/scmx/cf3ab31bc5031add81da)...

Comment: Thanks for directive link.